# iptables rules work only for me

Tags: networking, block, iptables

I need to block this ip  188.43.64.80.

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p ALL -d 188.43.64.80 -j DROP
```

This rule work for my local computer - i can't ping this ip.

But it's not working for computers which connected to me 
- they can ping this ip.

How can I make this rule to work in my network?

My network preferences - Internet from eth0.
                       Network from wlan0.

Comment: I guess such a question belongs to serverfault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in the `OUTPUT` chain, which only affects packets that this machine is outputting. You want to add a similar rule to the `FORWARD` chain which affects packets this machine is forwarding.